# Create bulk replace function in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a function in Excel using Visual Basic that will iterate through a table of values to search for in a string and replace.  For instance, given the table,

```
    [A]  [B]         
[1] foo  REPLACE1   
[2] bar  REPLACE2
```

I want the equation `=BULKREPLACE("I foo my bar.", Lists!A:A)` to render `I REPLACE1 my REPLACE2.`

I started writing the below code snippet, but realized I have no idea how to get this Visual Basic code to work, so decided to post here for help.

```
Function BULKREPLACE(Vcell As String, Vsearch As Range) As String

Dim Vwksht As String
Dim Vlastrow As Integer
Dim Vx1 As String
Dim Vrow As Integer

Vwksht = Vsearch.Worksheet.Name
Vlastrow = Vsearch.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Vx1 = Vcell

For Vrow = 2 To Vlastrow

  If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets(Vwksht).Range(Vsearch.Column & Vrow)) Then

    Vx1 = replace(Vx1, Worksheets(Vwksht).Range(Vsearch.Column & Vrow).Value, Worksheets(Vwksht).Range(Chr(Asc(Vsearch.Column) + 1) & Vrow).Value)

  End If

Next

BULKREPLACE = Vx1

End Function
```

I'd like the code to also iterate through each possible value. I just didn't get the loop statement in there.
Also, the table of lookup values will be stored in a different worksheet (`Lists`) than the worksheet using the `BULKREPLACE` function, so it's important to get the code to run the lookup on the defined sheet.

---

**Design Clarifications**

1. The function should be dynamic: able to be used multiple times, each time with different search and replace definitions.
2. The search and replace definitions are stored in a separate worksheet, always in two columns beside each other, and are user updatable. The definitions worksheet will also contain other data.
3. The function is designed for whole-word replacements only.

Comment: Is the dictionary table dynamic -- does it refer to different lists, or does the data in the list change over time? Otherwise you would be better off loading the data once into memory using a Dictionary and getting the values out of that.

Comment: Do you have multiple word replaces -- `foo my` should be replaced with `bar MY`? If not, consider using the Split function to split the string into words.

Comment: Is it acceptable to pass as the second argument to the function the string with the sheet name, or exact range eg replacement table first row `Lists!A1:A20`, but not the whole row `Lists!A:A`? Is there only one replacement table on the sheet or it contains another data? Do you intend to replace only the whole words (should `I foomy bar.` be replaced with `I REPLACE1my REPLACE2.`)?

Comment: In crafting an optimum solution, size matters.  Will you be processing a small number of cells and word/replacement pairs; or is this extensive?  Will you be typing in the data?  Or processing a previously prepared sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function BULKREPLACE(ByVal Vcell As String, ByRef Vsearch As Range) As String
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long

    If Len(Vcell) > 0 And Not Vsearch Is Nothing Then

        If Vsearch.Columns.Count = 1 Then

            lr = Vsearch.Cells(Vsearch.Row).End(xlDown).Row
            v = Vsearch.Resize(lr, Vsearch.Columns.Count + 1)

            For i = 1 To lr
                If Len(v(i, 1)) > 0 Then Vcell = Replace(Vcell, v(i, 1), v(i, 2))
            Next
        End If
    End If

    BULKREPLACE = Vcell
End Function
```

---

[image: BULKREPLACE]

It will use the first contiguous range in A:B for lookup values \ mapping

Answer (score 0):

You will need a transitional string variable to hold the changing value as you iterate through the possible changes. An option to provide case-sensitive or non-case-sensitive replacement (with a default value) might also be worthwhile.

```
Function BULKREPLACE(sTMP As String, rTERMS As Range, Optional bCASE As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim rWhat As Range

    For Each rWhat In rTERMS.Columns(1).Cells
        sTMP = Replace(sTMP, rWhat.Value2, rWhat.Offset(0, 1).Value2, 1, -1, _
                        IIf(bCASE, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare))
    Next rWhat

    BULKREPLACE = sTMP
End Function
```

Use like any native worksheet function. In the example image below this would be,

```
=BULKREPLACE(D4, $A$2:$B$3)
```

[image: Bulk Text Replacement UDF function]

Comment: @Brandon Lebedev - Added straight-from-string capability; can still be used with cell reference.

Comment: I like the bCASE option. Could you limit the function to whole-word matching? Right now it's replacing "lbark" with "lREPLACE2k". Also, it takes a long time. Could limiting rWhat with `Vsearch.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row` cut down on processing time?